# How do I reassure my old iPad that I am going to keep it?

Tags: ipad, ipados, setup

I got a new iPad mini 6th generation. I set up the new iPad by letting it pull from my old iPad mini 5th generation.

Now my old iPad is occasionally offering to assist in preparations for selling or giving it away. The offers include making backups, erasing data, wiping, etc.

But I don’t want to get rid of the older iPad. I will keep it, and use both the old iPad and the new iPad.

How do I stop these offers from reappearing? The only option shown is to “Remind me later”, so the offer to backup and wipe comes back later.

Comment: If you click through and then close it out does it come back?

Comment: Give it a pat and say to the iPad "It'll be ok, you're not going anywhere" haha! In all seriousness, would unlinking it from your iCloud account help at all, or even just signing out and back in? You could set up an additional iCloud account specific for your iPad, and then link it to your main iCloud account as a "Family member", that way your app purchases can be shared across the two iPads. Good luck!